# asp.net jquery id selector in content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".div_soru").toggle(function () {
            var cevap = "cevap" + $(this).attr("id");
            $("xxx").slideDown(); // 
        }, function () {
            var cevap = "cevap" + $(this).attr("id");
            $("xxx").slideUp();
        });
    });
</script>
```

in my content page :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_sorular" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_sss">
     <HeaderTemplate>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div>
             <div class="div_soru" id='<%# Eval("sss_id") %>'>
                   <strong><%# Eval("sss_baslik") %></strong>
             </div>
             <div class="div_cevap" id='<%# "cevap"+Eval("sss_id") %>' style="display: none; padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;">
                  <%# Eval("sss_icerik") %>
             </div>
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

in script code,i want write id=cevap, what i write instead of "xxx" i cant find correct syntax.
in master page , when write $("#" + cevap) it works. but in content page, it doesnt work.

thanks...

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way to do this using the `next` selector. Here's some example code:

```
​$(function(){
    $(".div_soru").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".div_cevap").show();
    });                                                                      
});​
```

The above example is simplified using the `click` event, but should adequately demonstrate the concept. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McQpU/) if you need further clarification.